# UISlider not moving to it's edge

Tags: ios, uislider

I am designing a slider and facing a problem, the thumb of the slider is not moving to it's end edge.

[image: See Screenshot]

I tried to subclass UISlider but didn't work. So please help me to sort out this problem.

Thank you.

Below is my code to this :

```
class CenteredThumbSlider: UISlider {

  override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect
  {
    let unadjustedThumbrect = super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
    let thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide:CGFloat = unadjustedThumbrect.size.width / 2.0
    let minOffsetToAdd = -thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide
    let maxOffsetToAdd = thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide
    let offsetForValue = minOffsetToAdd + (maxOffsetToAdd - minOffsetToAdd) * CGFloat(value / (self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue))
    var origin = unadjustedThumbrect.origin
    origin.x += offsetForValue
    return CGRect(origin: origin, size: unadjustedThumbrect.size)
  }

}
```

Comment: you should add some code

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code of your subclass, and to include the individual images you've used to override the default appearance.

Comment: did you try thumbRectForBounds ?

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you take the time to format your code so it is readable. You need to indent each line of code by an extra four spaces when you put it in your question. I fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UISlider and [implementthumbRect(forBounds:trackRect:value:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uislider/1621344-thumbrect) and [thumbImage(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uislider/1621342-thumbimage) to draw your triangle and [trackRect(forBounds:)](http://trackRect(forBounds:)) to draw the track.
I find it best to call super to get the default bounds and then just inset them by some amount (use a negative inset to make it bigger).  In your case you will also need to offset the y position of the thumb since it starts in the middle of the track by default.